# call third party server page in EXTJS page

Tags: javascript, json, extjs4

I am presently developing an EXTJS based portal making only asynchronous calls. The problem is that for only particular call in my portal, I have to access third party server which is like a black box to me with a reference ID. Third party server will process my request and generate results. I have to show these in my portal, and when user selects one of these results, selection has to be passed to both my server and the third party server. I want my portal to have minimum dependency on third party system. reference ID and data exchange is in JSON.

I cannot make any changes to the third party server. I am a starter so please excuse if my question is naive. If  you could direct me to some resources that would be fine too. I could have IFRAME but it spoils the consistency on my page. I also cannot lose the data entered by user prior to going to third party system.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JSONP. It is the only way to make a cross-domain request like this.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.JsonP